# jQuery - slideUp start fast and end slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a drop down menu which uses the `slideUp` feature in jQuery. I was wondering if I could remove the constant speed and start fast and end slow. I looked around and read about the `easing` method in `animate`, and I tried it, but it seems that it doesn't work for `slideUp`, only `animate` (if I am wrong please tell me); but otherwise, I cannot seem to figure it out. Any ideas? Here's my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = "fast";

    $("[data-action='dropdown']").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("body").click(function() {
        $("[data-action='dropdown'] ul ul").slideUp(h);
    });

    $("[data-action='dropdown'] ul li").click(function() {
        $("[data-action='dropdown'] ul ul").slideUp(h);

        $("ul", this).slideDown(h, function(){
            $("ul", this).slideUp(h);
        });
    });
});
```

The HTML is a very basic dropdown structure (just a `ul` element with `li`s and then inner `ul`s nested inside. Then in css, I make it to where the inner `ul ul` is hidden with a display of none, then, of course, is toggled by jQuery).

Any help would be very much appreciated! `:-)`

Comment: The [`.slideUp()` method](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) accepts an easing parameter, though there are only two easing options available in the core library. Did you read the doco?

Comment: Yes, but it seems `swing` and `linear` isn't the type I'm looking for exactly... Is there any magical way I could transform or modify either `swing or linear`?

Comment: You can use jQuery UI or some other [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) to get more options.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. I tried GSGD.co.uk's plugin but I looked in the error console and it says that the method I selected (`easeOutBounce`) is not defined, so I tried another, still undefined.

Comment: Okay, I see this alot on websites, it can't really be _that_ hard! XP

Comment: @ModernDesigner - See this: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: Yeah, @nnnnnn already referenced that. But for some reason it just doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the [jQuery easing plugin](https://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) to do this.

Include the jQuery easing Javascript file:

```html
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js
```

Then we can use the easing variables as a parameter in the `slideUp` function.

**Javascript**

```js
jQuery('#Example').slideUp({
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeOutCubic'
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s1ut0ong/)**

Comment: Ahh, thanks! Turns out I wasn't including the braces `{...}` Thanks!